# Force doctrine to use joined query to load entity

Tags: doctrine-orm, eager-loading

I have an entity that has many related entities that look like this:

```
Authorizable(one Authorization(many Role, many Acl))
User < Authorizable(
    many Profile < Authorizable
)
```

Loading the User entity and resolving the roles and acls takes about 15 queries and I would like to reduce that to a minimum (one ideally).

The `fetch="EAGER"` option does not seem to use joined queries.